# bitcoin: time of block size

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I'm trying to figure out the size of the block

and i have trouble calculating the number of bytes of time

one block has time like this:
"time":1516430234

After counting the bytes, the value is :5

This is a mistake, since it should be only 4

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: looking at bitcoin.org, and the blockchain reference, it says: "The block time is a Unix epoch time when the miner started hashing the header (according to the miner). Must be strictly greater than the median time of the previous 11 blocks...". So it is unclear, how you come to 5 or 4, maybe you can explain, what you do?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into the hex form.

[image]